# docker compose nginx reverse proxy to wrong container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file of a project server.It contains a `mongo` container, `nginx` service and a panel.

I have to containerize my service and the panel for both test and main environements.Firstly I publish on test, afterwards I publish on main.

After the publishing on main `nginx` forward requests to test and that is the issue.

Restarting the `nginx` fixes the problem, so how can I fix the issue permanantly without restarting `nginx` after each publish on the main environement.

`docker-compose.yml` :

```yaml
    version: '3.7'
    
    services:   main-mongo:
        image: mongo:4.2.3
        container_name: main-mongo
        volumes:
          - mongodb:/data/db
          - mongoconfig:/data/configdb
    
      main_service:
        image: project
        container_name: main_service
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
          - ./views:/project/views
          - ./public:/project/public
        depends_on:
          - main-mongo
    
      test_service:
        image: test_project
        container_name: test_service
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
          - ./test_view/views:/project/views
          - ./test_view/public:/project/public
        environment:
          - ENV=test
        depends_on:
          - main-mongo
    
      test_panel:
        image: test_panel
        container_name: test_panel
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
          - ENV=test
        depends_on:
          - main-mongo
    
      main_panel:
        image: panel
        container_name: main_panel
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
          - main-mongo
    
      python_backend_test:
        image: python_backend_test
        container_name: python_backend_test
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
          - /tmp:/tmp
    
      nginx:
        image: nginx:1.17
        container_name: nginx
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
          - 80:80
        volumes:
          - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
          - ./panel_front:/usr/share/panel
        depends_on:
          - main_panel
          - test_panel
          - test_service
          - main_service
        volumes:   mongodb:   mongoconfig:
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain.com;
        location /api {
           proxy_pass http://main_panel:3000;
        }
        location /account {
           root /usr/share/panel/live;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://main_service:3000;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name test.domain.com;
        location /netflix {
            proxy_pass http://python_backend_test:5000;
        }
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://test_panel:3000;
        }
        location /account {
           alias /usr/share/panel/test/;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://test_service:3000;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue.
I solve the problem with creating network for `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a network for you project and add all of your containers to that network.

It's more clear that default network.default network may conflict.